# How can we get the subteam ID of a slack usergroup in the new SLACK UI?

Tags: slack

I want to know the ID of a subteam/usergroup manually.

I know in the old UI we go to "People and usergroups" in the slack web browser and search for the usergroup and get it in the URL, and i can see "People" Tab in the new Slack UI and am able to search for the usergroup, but i don't see any ID in the URL. It just gives https://app.slack.com/client/E12345678/people.

I need the manual way to find the ID of a usergroup and NOT the api way.

Comment: i dont think its possible

Comment: I did find a way which is weird, it's in the network tab in the browser console in the usergroup detail payload but this is just too nested. I seriously hope Slack has NOT removed this flow of getting the subteam ID from the URL, or else it's going to be annoying!